# Can I use a gitolite repository on a non-default port from windows?

Tags: git, ssh, cmd, msysgit, gitolite

I'm trying to set up some git repositories on my linux server for sharing with some friends working on a Java project. I sniffed around a little and found gitolite was supposed to be a good administration layer, so after looking at their docs I decided to follow this tutorial:

http://sites.google.com/site/senawario/home/gitolite-tutorial

Everything went well until step 6. There, the syntax used for the repository path wasn't working because sshd on the server isn't listening on the default port and that syntax doesn't like non-default ports, so after some more research I quickly discovered git supports ssh://etc. The only issue would be that it requires the full repository path to be included in the URL.

When I reached step 7 and the admin repository failed to push, I discovered that gitolite doesn't like full paths. I was advised by the troubleshooting section to create a host alias like so:

http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/sshhostaliases.html

This would supposedly allow me to use hostalias:reponame as the path. Despite the annoyance of requiring every user to do this, we went with that method, only to find out that it's not working at all. Our users are running windows and msysgit.

To summarize:

- The server's sshd listens on a non-default port; this cannot be changed.
- gitolite seems to require relative paths. Relative paths are only available on the default port or using host aliases.
- Our users are running windows 7 (not changeable) and msysgit (changeable, if there's anything better out there?). Our setups don't seem to like host aliases.

Is there a solution for this or do we have to drop gitolite and find something else?

Answer (score 0):

See if editing `~/.ssh/config` (from msysgit) works for each user. Add something like the following to the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host gitserver
Port 9999
```

The file [`~/.ssh/config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) is optional and is used by ssh if it exists. Also, the `~/.ssh` directory must not be readable to others (`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`).

When accessing git repo serverd using gitolite you're actually using the ssh transport. To be sure that ssh (and indirectly, git) uses the file `~/.ssh/config` you can try the following diagnosis:

```
$ ssh -v gitserver
```

The first few lines that start with the `debug1:` prefix will tell you if ssh is using the `~/.ssh/config` file - it will show you the full path the the config file that it uses.

Comment: As written on the question, I'm afraid msysgit is ignoring the contents of the file. The file didn't exist in first place, only the directory, so I'm not even sure I'm using the right file for msysgit though.

Comment: It does not show any config file path. It does show that it's connecting to the correct server hostname as included in the config file, however it's ignoring the port and trying 22. Very strange.